# rails How to pass parameters as part of the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I trying to create a dynamic url which will pass params through it. 
My code look like that :

```
def self.mailer(user)
  url = user_UserByEmail_url(user.user_token)
  @text = "#{url} click here to navigate"
  subject = "Hello World"
  mail(subject: subject, to: ###)
end
```

then in my routes.rb look like that:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  collection do
    get :UserByEmail
  end
end
```

and, in my users controller I have the function :

```
before_filter :find_userEmail

def find_userEmail
  @user = User.find_by_user_token(params[:id])
end

def UserByEmail
  url =  "#{GLOBAL[:url]}/champion_declined//#{companyToken}"
  redirect_to url
end
```

but, when I run the very first method with the: `url = user_UserByEmail_url(user.user_token)`

I got the error:

> undefined method `user_UserByEmail_url'

Comment: It looks like you do not understand how routing works in rails. Instead of giving you a fish, I'll teach you how to fish. Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: can you run `rake routes` I dont think that you have the right path/url user_UserByEmail_url

Comment: You should probably check the Ruby naming conventions before writing more code.

Comment: @simoneCarletti I have a place in my code (i didn't wrote it) that works exactly like that